# data-ng-repeat in partial view does not display data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my module.js

```
            var app = angular.module("ApplicationModule", ["ngRoute"]);

            app.factory("ShareData", function () {  
            return { value: 0 }  
            });  

            //Showing Routing  
            app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function      
            ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            debugger;
            $routeProvider.when('/ShowAll',
                    {
                        templateUrl: 'Home/ShowAll',
                        controller: 'ShowAllController'
                    });
                    $routeProvider.otherwise(
                    {
                       redirectTo: '/'
                     });
                    }]);
```

This is my Services.js

```
                app.service("SampleService", function ($http) {
                this.getSamples = function () {
                return $http.get("/api/Sample");
                };
                this.getSample = function (id) {
                return $http.get("/api/Sample" + id);
                }; 
                });
```

This is my ShowAllController.js

```
                  app.Controller('ShowAllController', function ($scope,          
                  SampleService) {
                  loadAll();
                  function loadAll() {
                  var promiseGet = SampleService.getSamples();
                  promiseGet.success(function (data) { $scope.Samples = data           
                  },
                  function (errordata) {
                  $scope.error = errordata;
                  }
                  );
                  }
                  });
```

This is my index.cshtml

```
                   @{
                       ViewBag.Title = "API's";
                    }
                   @section scripts{
                   <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
                   <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
                   <script src="~/Scripts/Module.js"></script>
                   <script src="~/Scripts/Services.js"></script>
                   <script src="~/Scripts/ShowAllController.js"></script>
                    }
                   <div class="container" data-ng-app="ApplicationModule">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-header">
    <div class="row">
<div><h4 class="col-xs-6">GET api/Patient</h4><a href="#/ShowAll" class="btn btn-success col-xs-6" role="button">Patients List</a></div>
</div></div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-ng-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is my partial view (ShowAll.cshtml)

```
               <div data-ng-controller="ShowAllController">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Age</th>
                 <th>Address</th>
                   </tr>
                 <tr data-ng-repeat="person in Samples">
                 <td>{{person.Id}}</td>
                  <td>{{person.Name}}</td>
                 <td>{{person.Age}}</td>
                  <td>{{person.Address}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                   </div>
```

My return PartialView code is in my HomeController inside the ShowAll ActionResult. The problem is that when I click the button it just displays the header of the table without the data.

Note: This is a web api.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following statement to your ShowAllController before the ajax call so Angular is aware of this scope var in Config time

```
app.Controller('ShowAllController', function ($scope, SampleService) {

    $scope.Samples = []; // <- NEW LINE HERE!

    loadAll();
    function loadAll() {
    var promiseGet = SampleService.getSamples();
    promiseGet.success(function (data) { $scope.Samples = data           
    },
    function (errordata) {
    $scope.error = errordata;
    }
    );
    }
});
```

Angular Dependency Injection might not be setting up the scope var `Samples` in Config time. Then in Run time, it won't recognize this var as something that should be updated.

If that doesn't work, also try to wrap the success result of of your promise into `$scope.$apply()` as angular might not be aware of it when running its digest function.

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.Samples = data;
})
```

Comment: I already did but I'm still getting the same result. Is it because it's in my partial view?